# Finding the directional derivative of f(x,y).

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let the directional derivative of a function $f(x,y)$ at a point $P$ in the direction of $(1/\sqrt{5})\mathbf{i}+(2/\sqrt{5})\mathbf{j}$ be $16/\sqrt{5}$ and the partial derivative $\partial f / \partial x$ evaluated at $P$ be $6$. Then what is the directional derivative in the direction of $\mathbf{i}-\mathbf{j}$?

I got $1$ as the answer but this is incorrect. It should come out to $1/\sqrt{2}$.

My work so far:

$D(P)=(f_x,f_y)\cdot(1/\sqrt{5},2/\sqrt{5}) $

if $\partial f/ \partial x=6$ then $6+2f_y=16 \implies f_y=5$

so $(1\cdot6)+(5\cdot(-1))=1$.

Comment: You forgot to normalise $i-j$ (I take it that is part of your definition) into $\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{j}{\sqrt{2}}$. This would give you your factor of $1/\sqrt{2}$!

Comment: Also you have a factor of $16/\sqrt{5}j$ but in your calculation you assume $2/\sqrt{5}$; am I right to suggest that this was a typo in copying over the question?

Comment: @ChrisK oh yes that was a typo, and thank you! i forgot about that part

Answer (score 1):

The directional derivative of $f(x,y)$ along some unit vector $\mathbf{v}$ is $\nabla f(x,y) \cdot \mathbf{v}$.

Applying this to the given in the problem:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{16}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Using the value ${\partial f}/{\partial x} = 6$, we get ${\partial f}/{\partial y} = 5$. Thus, $\nabla f = (6,5)$, and $\nabla f \cdot (1,-1)/\sqrt{2}=1/\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 0):

The differential of $f$ at the given point $P$ is a linear map, respresented by a $1\times 2$ matrix, namely $f'(P)=\left(\displaystyle\frac{df}{dx}(P),\ \frac{df}{dy}(P)\right)$. Now, by assumption,
$df/dx(P)=6$, and let $b:=df/dy(P)$ the missing coordinate.

The other piece of information tells us that
$$\pmatrix{6&b}\cdot\pmatrix{1/\sqrt5 \\ 2/\sqrt5} = \frac{16}{\sqrt5}\,.$$
From this you can express $b$ and calculate
$$\pmatrix{6&b}\cdot\pmatrix{1 \\ -1}\,.$$
(Or *normalize* the vector $(1,\,-1)^T$, dividing it by its length, $\sqrt2$.)